# why don't we get the odd number of cores in a processor?

Tags: multicore

Why we do no have a processor with odd number of cores? Why don't the manufacturing companies prefer odd number of cores to even number of cores?

Comment: We do. I have VMs that have one core. QED.

Comment: The Xbox 360 has a [tri-core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xenon_(processor)) processor.

Comment: ya i know that. But Why do these manufacturing companies(like Intel) always produce processors with even number of core? what is the advantage of producing even number of cores?